# How to make the background of my subpages different than my home page?

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

my home page has one background with the `CSS`

```
body { 
background-image: url(image.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
background-position: 0px ;
background-attachment: fixed;
 }
```

and all of my subpages have the same background, but I would like to change them.

The HTML for the toolbar that leads to the subpages, under Tumblr's "Custom Theme":

```
<body class="pages"><ul class='section' id='section_1'>
<li><span id='section_title_1' class='section_title'><a href='https://website.com/' id='section_link_1'>past projects</a></span>
<ul>
<li id='slide_01' class='slide_title'><center><a href='https://website.com/subpage/'>TITLE</a></center></li>
<li id='slide_02' class='slide_title'><center><a href='https://website.com/subpage/'>TITLE</a></center></li>
</ul> 
</li>
</ul>
```

I tried adding something like

```
ul.class { 
background-image: url(image2.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
background-position: 0px ;
background-attachment: fixed;
 }
```

above it but it only changed the background of the toolbar text and not the subpages.

And on Tumblr I click on a different window to edit the subpages, which have an `HTML` section that looks like:

```
<div id="exhibit">
<div class="container">
<div class="top"><!-- --></div>
<div id="img-container2">
<div class="picture" id="node001" style="width: 400px;">
<div></div>
<div class="captioning text2" style="width: 750px; height: 30px;">
<div style="padding: 0 10px 0 0;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="separator" style="float: left; width: 10px;">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="picture" id="node002" style="max-width: 100%;">
<div><img class="done" height="600" src="https://displayimage.png" /></div>
<div class="captioning text2" style="max-width: 100%; height: 30px;">
<div style="padding: 0 10px 0 0;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and I tried to put this before that on this specific page editor

```
body { 
background-image: url(image2.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
background-position: 0px ;
background-attachment: fixed;
 }
```

or

```
body2 { 
background-image: url(image2.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
background-position: 0px ;
background-attachment: fixed;
z-index: 999
 }
```

but nothing happened to the subpages. Similar advice on here say to look for things like `<body id="menu">` or `<body id="contact-us">` and I may be able to go from there if I knew where that was with regards to the `HTML` on my subpage, and I don't know.

-
Thanks for the suggestions! Today I have the `CSS` set up like

```
body { 
background-image: url(image.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
background-position: 0px ;
background-attachment: fixed;
 }
 
body.subpages { 
background-image: url(image2.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat;
background-position: 0px ;
background-attachment: fixed;
 }
```

and the `HTML` in the other window is currently

```
<body class="subpages">
<div id="exhibit">
<div class="container">
<div class="top"><!-- --></div>
<div id="img-container2">
<div class="picture" id="node001" style="width: 400px;">
<div></div>
<div class="captioning text2" style="width: 750px; height: 30px;">
<div style="padding: 0 10px 0 0;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="separator" style="float: left; width: 10px;">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="picture" id="node002" style="max-width: 100%;">
<div><img class="done" height="600" src="https://displayimage.png" /></div>
<div class="captioning text2" style="max-width: 100%; height: 30px;">
<div style="padding: 0 10px 0 0;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

This doesn't change the background at all so far. Two setups I tried an hour ago that did change the background to the second image were

```
body { 
background-image: url(image.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
background-position: 0px ;
background-attachment: fixed;
 }

body.core { 
background-image: url(image2.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
background-position: 0px ;
background-attachment: fixed;
 }
```

```
body { 
background-image: url(image.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
background-position: 0px ;
background-attachment: fixed;
 }

body:not([id="subpages"]) { 
background-image: url(image.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
background-position: 0px ;
background-attachment: fixed;
 }
```

But they all changed the backgrounds to image #2 across the board (both home and subpage). I think I am having trouble differentiating subpage ID and main page ID from each other and their location.

Any advice or tips are appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If the main page does not have an ID on the body, but the subpages do, you could use a selector like:
`body[id]` to select the subpages and override the base `body` styles.

Alternatively you could use `body:not([id="home"])` (or whatever the ID on your home page) to override the default for subpages.

Another option is to set the default `body` style for the subpages and then override that with `#home` (or `body#home`) (or whatever your home ID is) with the background for that page.

Comment: Reusable classes are almost always better than one-off IDs.

Comment: 100% agree.  I would say this case is why we say "almost always".  In this case it seems the markup is out of their control.  The ID is generated by the CMS, and corresponds to the page, which would allow a targeted selector which also overrides a base default via specificity.  The attribute selector can be used to reduce the specificity for other overrides, but in this case I think it fits the scenario.

Comment: Hello, where do I determine where the main page ID and the subpages ID are? I used ```body:not([id="home"])``` as a copy of the first ```CSS``` under it and it overrode everything with the new image, not just one page.

Comment: @grovee : I used 'home' as an example.  You would have to inspect the page code to determine whether or not there's an ID you can use.  Really all you need is a selector that is unique to each page, if there is one.  I can't really tell specifics from the HTML you posted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use different classes for the `body` element on the different subpages and create CSS rules for those classes, either with or without the `body` appended in the CSS selectors, like

```
body {
  [...main settings...]
}
body.yourclass1 {
  [...other settings...]
}
```

In HTML, the opening `body` tag for the first subpage would look like this:

```
<body class="yourclass1">
```

And so on, with as many classes as you like. You could also use IDs instead, it doesn't really make much difference, as long as you use it only in the `body` tag, i.e. only *once*  in an HTML document.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the tips! I am running into an issue though; I have the ```css``` set up like your comment but everytime I enter ```<body class="yourclass1"></body>``` around the ```html``` of the subpage and click save and leave, it disappears when I reenter the ```html``` section. And the background doesn't change at all or for just one page.